# What are $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, terminology-and-notation

On a view places, I've seen kets that look like this $\left|+\right>$ or this $\left|-\right>$ but I don't seem to find any explanation of this base online. Is it just a different notation for $0$ and $1$, or does it mean something else? Thanks for your help!

Comment: $|\pm \rangle  = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|0\rangle \pm |1\rangle)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does this Notation have any particular name, as I was not able to find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set $\{ \left|+\right>, \left|-\right> \}$ is known as the polar basis. It easy to see that they are the result of applying the Hadamard transform $H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ to the standard basis vectors of a one-dimensional Hilbert space:
$$
H\left|0\right> = \left| + \right>,
$$
$$
H\left|1\right> = \left| - \right>.
$$
You can read more about them Hadamard transform [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform).

Comment: I would just add that the basis is sometimes called Hadamard basis or x-basis.

Comment: There is |0> and |1>. Why do we need different basis (in quantum computation), like polar basis and others?